# Mocha Chai tests strange closure behaviour

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, phantomjs, mocha.js, chai

Does anyone know how the closures work in a Mocha + Chai test? I'm not sure if the test runner, in this case phantom-js, is messing things up but it just doesn't make any sense. It would appear that vars created in each it function block clash with each other.

Basically a game can only have 10 players, but in every tests the game var already has 10 players in it. Very confusing.

```
"use strict";

CardsAgainstHumanity.module("Game", function(Game, CardsAgainstHumanity, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
    Game.Game = Backbone.Model.extend({
        maxPlayers: 10,
        defaults: {
            players: new CardsAgainstHumanity.Player.PlayerCollection()
        },
        addPlayer: function(player){
            if(this.get("players").size() < this.maxPlayers){
                this.get("players").add(player);
            }
            else{
                throw(Error("This game is currently full"));
            }
        },
        removePlayer: function(player){
            this.get("players").remove(player);
        }
    });
});

describe.only("players can be added and removed", function(){
    it("should add a player if there is space", function(){
        var game = new CardsAgainstHumanity.Game.Game();
        var player = new CardsAgainstHumanity.Player.Player({
            id: 1
        });
        game.addPlayer(player);
        game.get("players").contains(player).should.be.true;
    });
    it("should not add a player if the game is full", function(){
        var game = new CardsAgainstHumanity.Game.Game();
        _.times(game.maxPlayers, function(index){
            var game = new CardsAgainstHumanity.Game.Game();
            game.addPlayer(new CardsAgainstHumanity.Player.Player({
               id: index
            }));
        });
        (function(){
            game.addPlayer(new CardsAgainstHumanity.Player.Player({
                id: game.maxPlayers
             }));
        }).should.throw(Error("This game is currently full"));
    });
    it("should remove said player if said player is found", function(){
        var game = new CardsAgainstHumanity.Game.Game();
        var player = new CardsAgainstHumanity.Player.Player({
            id: 1
        });
        game.addPlayer(player);
        game.get("players").contains(player).should.be.true;
        game.removePlayer(player);
        game.get("players").contains(player).should.be.false;
    });
```

Comment: From what evidence are you inferring that ``game`` has 10 players in every one of your tests?

Comment: In every test case the game throws an exception when any player is added. I ran it in a real browser and the game var had 10 players on the first test.

Comment: A custom error to say the game is full. Which gets thrown when you try to add the 11th player.

Comment: I've added the game class so you can see what it does. It hardly does anything at the moment. I was trying to write it TDD style but it hasn't gone very well!

Comment: From the POV of using Mocha, I'm just not seeing what the problem could be. I've used Mocha extensively but I'm not familiar with Backbone. It might help if you dropped one of the tags you've put up (I would suggest removing ``unit-testing``) and added ``Backbone`` as a tag, so that Backbone experts see your question.

Comment: are you sure maxPlayers is defined on 'this' in the `addPlayer` function. I'd log that out to make sure you are scoping properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red flag I see is this:

```
defaults: {
    players: new CardsAgainstHumanity.Player.PlayerCollection()
}
```

A Backbone model's [`defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) are attached to the model's prototype and are shallow copied to each instance's attributes. With a `defaults` like that, each instance of the model you create will end up sharing **exactly the same** `PlayerCollection`. That could explain why your `players` is always ending up full when you don't expect it to be.

The usual solution to this sort of thing is to use a function for `defaults`:

```
defaults: function() {
    return {
        players: new CardsAgainstHumanity.Player.PlayerCollection()
    };
}
```

That way each instance will get its own unique defaults object and thus its own unique `PlayerCollection` in its `players` attribute. Generally you should use a function for your `defaults` any time it contains a mutable value (i.e. anything other than numbers, strings, and booleans).

If my guess is right then you have a win for your test suite as it has uncovered a hidden and tricky bug.

Comment: Oohh well spotted! I never thought about that. I'll try when I get home!